# How to print smiley face in Tcl

Tags: tcl

I have a smiley face pattern in plain text saved as a file called smile.txt

How do I print this file's content on my tool's console/terminal?

The goal was to print a smiley face when my code is successfully executed. Instead of writing puts "XXX" line by line I thought it might be easier this way.

Answer (score 3):

This is a known bug in the handling of Unicode characters outside the Basic Multilingual Plane (i.e., greater than U+00FFFF). We hope to have it fixed in 8.7; it is being actively worked on.

### Workaround

As a workaround, this works for me but it might not work for you:

```
set t [fconfigure stdout -encoding]
fconfigure stdout -encoding iso8859-1
puts "\xF0\x9F\x98\x89"
fconfigure stdout -encoding $t
```

That's the sequence of bytes required in UTF-8, so flipping the encoding to ISO 8859-1 temporarily (that encoding is special as it “just writes the bytes” if you can generate them) lets you generate the sequence you need.

Comment: I used a winking smiley for testing. 

Comment: ð This is what I get.

Comment: It won't work on Windows (where the true console has some very “interesting” code to glue it to Tcl), or in any window rendered by Tk. Those require the actual bug fix, and we've not yet finalised it. Or maybe things will work on Windows if you send the smiley encoded as surrogate pairs. You'll need to experiment there. (Remember: you're in an area where Tcl is **known** to be buggy. Platform-inconsistent behaviour is — unfortunately — not surprising.)